# How to handle a global context object in the following scenario?

Tags: python, class, oop, design-patterns

I have these two classes:

```
class TestSuite(object):
    def __init__(self, context):
        self._tests = [
            Test(test_data) for test_data in context["tests"] 
        ]
        self.context = context

    @property
    def runtime(self):
        try:
            return RuntimeFactory.create_runtime(self.context)
        except:
            print("runtime_id is missing or invalid, handle with with a proper exception")

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, context):
        self.context = context
```

The `context` object here contains the data based on which all the classes in the application lifecycle get instantiated. Now, inside the `Test` class, I need the `runtime` property of `TestSuite`, because all `Test` instances share the same runtime naturally.

My problem is,

1. If I pass the full `context` throughout the application flow, I can't know inside a `Test` object which test I am dealing with (as it's a list with no explicit index).
2. If I pass `context["tests"][index]` inside `Test`object as local `context`, I lose the `context["runtime"]`.

Now, I can pass two `context` (`runtime_context` and `test_context`), but that kind of violates the whole purpose of a `context` object (To pass one single `context`, which moves around the app, and classes use it as needed).

I can think of some solutions:

1. Update the local `context` by adding `runtime` as a key before creating each `Test` object.
2. Create the `Test` objects with local `context` and assign the `runtime` attribute of `Test` object from `TestSuite` class.
3. Create the `Test` objects with global `context` and assign an `index/id` attribute to `Test` object from `TestSuite` class.

But none of this seems quite convincing to me. I have this situation on different layers (A test has a list of input for example), changing all those classes make the code a bit messy in my opinion.

Any suggestion of how I can solve this problem in a pythonic way with less coupling.

Comment: It's unclear. For example, how many instances of 'context ' do you want to create? And what are their lifecycle? If it has a singleton nature, why not use a global variable or a class variable? Why don't you distinguish between the context and data for a specific test object?

Comment: @relent95 so `context` here IS of singleton nature. `context` here is a big dictionary (loaded from a json file) that contains all the necessary info about how to run the Testsuite. (Which runtime the tests should run on), and also for individual tests, the inputs, output etc. Ideally I want a single `context` object flow across the app, so that every class can use the respective portion of information. The problem arises, when I am initializing a specific Test object, because there along with that test specific data, I also need to carry the runtime with me.

Comment: You are better to give an example of data in the context. How will you map a test specific data and test object? And why not just give the context and a test specific data to the ```Test.__init__()```?